# Highcharts markers to appear only on x axis ticks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highchart which displays hourly data while the x axis is set to a daily tick interval. What I get is a graph with markers on hours (24 between every tick). 
Is there a way to display the markers only where there is tick? Is there a 'marker interval'?

**EDIT**

To simplify my question - If we look at this chart http://jsfiddle.net/kmdbqg1w/1/

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
},
```

I want the markers to appear only when it's 1.Jan and 2.Jan on the x axis and not anywhere between them (or after 2.Jan), yet to have the data between them appear on tooltip.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control markers by `series.marker` option.

Disable markers in the series

```
series: [{
  marker: {enabled: false},
```

Enable markers for the points you want:

```
data: [
  [1483225200000,0],
  {x: 1483228800000, y: 23, marker: {enabled: true}},
  [1483232400000,46]
]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/p1wfopxb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use plotOptions  options, max and min properties of axis like below

```
 plotOptions : {
            series  : {
                pointStart      : 0,
                pointInterval   : 5
            }
        },

 xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 5,
        min:0,
        max:10
    },
```

see this updated link
http://jsfiddle.net/qvwt6mjr/

Comment: good thinking!
However, it doesn't seem to work for me yet. maybe because i use timestamps

Comment: I've edited my question and added a better example of my case